# Is Instagram API compatible with OpenID Connect?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, instagram, instagram-api, amazon-cognito

Is **Instagram API** compatible with **OpenID Connect** ? I want to implement instagram login functionality with AWS Cognito.

Answer (score 3):

Not as far as I know. It does support simple [OAuth2](https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/) and has endpoints like /authorize etc. but there is no OIDC discovery document (.well-known/openid-configuration). So, you won't be able to directly integrate it with AWS Cognito as an OIDC Auth provider.

What you can do is use the Custom provider option (developer authentication) and manually get an id. Use your application to get Instragram user's id -

- authenticate using OAuth2
- get an access token
- use the sub claim as an id or use the access token to get some other detail and use it as an id)
- Once you get the data you want to use as an id, use as developer user identifier in [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) to get Cognito Identity Id and Token.